# Tomcat H2 deployment

Tags: java, database, hibernate, configuration, h2

I have 2 situations.

```
hibernate.cfg:
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:log4jdbc:h2:./H2/test</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
```

1. H2 db is in my project near my src folder. If I try to test connection from simple class it works. It connects to the db that is in the right place in project folder.
2. Now I'm making new configuration to launch tomcat + servlets. All is fine, but tomcat creates new H2 database in his folder: (apache-tomcat-8.0.17\bin\H2\test.mv.db). Is it possible to make tomcat to take (to use) my test.mv.db from my project's folder ?
   If I put my test.mv.db manualy from project into tomcat's dir - it is working (I'm not using "sa" with blank password). I don't want to place h2 db into user's folder like jdbc:h2:~/test).

Thank you.

Comment: Have your tried hard-coding the path in the connection.url property value?  The user that Tomcat is running as will require permission to access that directory and file.

Comment: No, I didn't. Also they say that it happens this way because of 'embedded' and that I should try using H2 as a server then.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should append the `hibernate` prefix to all your properties.
2. Try giving H2 an absolute path to your database folder:

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:/your-project-path/test-db</property>
   ```
3. I don't think the Driver class setting is correct either. It should be:

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
   ```

Comment: I could be wrong - absolute path is a good thing but what if I move and deploy this project in the other place ? Path will be broken. I am launching tomcat right from the IDEA to see how my project works. I did not try to make war - place it in the tomcat webapps to see how it works there. About that driver: That driver is log4jdbc's driver, since I need log4jdbc to work.

Comment: 1. You can and should use Maven to configure the DB properties too and the db path is one such setting. 2. Make sure you have log4jdbc.auto.load.popular.drivers settings on.